# Why is my azure devops variable not evaluated as bool?

Tags: azure-devops

## Question

Can i cast my type to bool, so it works without `eq()` when declaring the variable or am i stuck with the version that works?

### my variables

```
variables:
  - name: BUILD_PUBLISH_ARTIFACTS
    value: ${{or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))}}
  - name: BUILD_IS_RELEASE
    value: ${{startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/')}}
  - name: BUILD_IS_ALPHA
    value: ${{eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')}}
```

### this works

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['BUILD_PUBLISH_ARTIFACTS'], 'True'))
```

### this does not work (but i want it to work like this)

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), variables['BUILD_PUBLISH_ARTIFACTS'])
```

[image: screenshot of yaml build pipeline]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can i cast my type to bool, so it works without eq() when declaring
>   the variable or am i stuck with the version that works?

I think you don't need to cast that to bool. I tried all you scripts and they all worked well on my side. If `eq(variables['BUILD_PUBLISH_ARTIFACTS'], 'True')` can work, then in your condition `variables['BUILD_PUBLISH_ARTIFACTS']` should also work.

Apart from above combinations, I also tried `condition: and(variables['BUILD_xxx'],eq(variables['BUILD_xxx'], 'True'))`, it also worked. So you don't need to cast that to bool, the `And()` can recognize them well.

In my opinion, you issue may result after you've done several changes to pipeline. Did you test these two scripts in same scenario? Same pipeline with same branch?

Click this button and you'll find the direct cause of your issue:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is the weird thing - i also added a build step to print my variables which returned True/False which prompted me to try `eq(variables[], '')` whenever i used `and(succeeded(), variables[])` both steps ran instead of just the one i wanted, even though juding by the expanded variables only one step should have executed. Is there perhaps a difference when the variable is a compiled/runtime expression?

Comment: I'm not sure if this strange issue has something to do with compiled/runtime expression, cause I can't reproduce it in my machine. The two formats always give me the same result, both ran or both skip(not run). Have you clicked the button to get further info like what I shows in the end of answer? Can it give you some hints?

Comment: i don't get the tooltip you show in the screenshot. Are you using a pure yaml build pipeline? If you look at this screenshot, which i added to the question, you'll see another noteworthy thing - the variable expands to `'True'` instead of `True`

Comment: Yes, I also use the yaml pipeline  to do the test. And in my test, when condition=> and(True,'True'), it seems to work.

Comment: aha! that might be the reason. you use `and`, i used `eq`. I'll have  look at my pipeline shortly.